# How can I make sure that block of code in unit test will be runned after batch ends - not before or during test?

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, asynchronous

I need to run batch (or something else which will process big amount of records) and after this branch I need to invoke

```
System.assert(booleanVariable);
```

How can I do this? Batch need to execute and finish before this block of code.

Answer (score 3):

Using `startTest` and `stopTest` will allow you to assert once the batch operation is completed.

```
Test.startTest();
// invoke batch
Test.stopTest();
// assert results
```

Asynchronous calls made during the test are finalised when you call `Test.stopTest()` allowing you to test the results of asynchronous logic.

> All asynchronous calls made after the startTest method are collected by the system. When stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes are run synchronously.